# How do I get FillInTheBlank to print a question(Inheritance)

Tags: java, class, inheritance, error-handling

I am new to inheritance and am having issues finishing an assignment. My error is that I am receiving a stack overflow error.

The assisgnment is consisting of a class heirarchy to print a test and answer key each different class is a different type of question. My program can print an object quesiton but not a fill in the blank question

Any help or point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Driver.java

```
package assignment9testpapers;

public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test trial = new Test( 3, 3);
        ObjectiveQuestion obj = new ObjectiveQuestion( 3,  2,  1, "what is 1 + 1",  "2");
        trial.addObjectiveQuestion(obj);
        ObjectiveQuestion fitbl = new FillInTheBlankQuestion(3 ,2 ,1 , "Who is the professor of 1068", "John Fiore");
        trial.addFillInTheBlankQuestion(fitbl);
        trial.printTest();
        trial.printTestAnswers();
    }
}
```

question.java

```
1 package assignment9testpapers;
2
3 public class Question {
4   private int points;
5   private int difficulty;
6   private int answerSpace;
7   private String questionText;
8   
9   public final int MIN_DIFFICULTY = 1;
10  public final int MAX_DIFFICULTY = 5;
11
12  public Question(int points, int difficulty, int answerSpace, String 
 questionText) {
13      this.points = points;
14  this.answerSpace = answerSpace;
15      this.questionText = questionText;
16      
17      if(difficulty>=MIN_DIFFICULTY && difficulty <= MAX_DIFFICULTY) {
18          this.difficulty=difficulty;
19      }else if(difficulty<MIN_DIFFICULTY) {
20          this.difficulty=MIN_DIFFICULTY;
21      } else {
22          this.difficulty=MAX_DIFFICULTY;
23      }
24  }
25  
26  public String toString(){
27      return "Points" + points+ "difficulty" + difficulty +"question" + questionText;
28  }
29  
30  public String getQuestionText() {
31      return questionText+makeAnswerSpace();
32  }
33  
34  public int getPoints() {
35      return points;
36  }
37  
38  private String makeAnswerSpace() {
39      String space="";
40      for(int i = 0; i<answerSpace; i++) {
41          space+='\n';
42      }
43      return space;
44  }
```

ObjectiveQuestion.java

```
package assignment9testpapers;

public class ObjectiveQuestion extends Question {
    private String correctAnswer;

    public ObjectiveQuestion(int points,int difficulty, int answerSpace, String questionText, String correctAnswer ) {
        super(points, difficulty, answerSpace, questionText);
        this.correctAnswer=correctAnswer;
    }

    public String getCorrectAnswer() {
        return correctAnswer;
    }


}
```

test.java

```
package assignment9testpapers;

public class Test {
    private String[] questions;
    private String[] answer;
    private int totalPoints;

    private int questionCount = 0;

    public Test(int numQuestions, int totalPoints) {
        this.questions = new String[numQuestions];
        this.answer = new String[numQuestions];
        this.totalPoints=totalPoints;
    }

    public void addObjectiveQuestion(ObjectiveQuestion q) {
        questions[questionCount] = q.getQuestionText();
        answer[questionCount]=q.getCorrectAnswer();
        questionCount++;
    }

    public void addMultipleChoiceQuestion(MultipleChoiceQuestion q) {
        questions[questionCount] = q.getQuestionText();
        answer[questionCount]=q.getCorrectAnswer();
        questionCount++;
    }

    public void addFillInTheBlankQuestion(ObjectiveQuestion q) {
        questions[questionCount] = q.getQuestionText();
        answer[questionCount]=q.getCorrectAnswer();
        questionCount++;
    } 




    public void printTest() {
        for (int i = 0; i<questions.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(questions[i]);
        }
    }

    public void printTestAnswers() {
        for (int i = 0; i<answer.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(answer[i]);
        }
    }   
}
```

FillInTheBlankQuestion.java

```
package assignment9testpapers;

public class FillInTheBlankQuestion extends ObjectiveQuestion{

    public FillInTheBlankQuestion(int points,int difficulty, int answerSpace, String questionText, String correctAnswer ) {
        super(points, difficulty, answerSpace, questionText, correctAnswer);
    }

    public String getQuestionText() {
        return "______________" + getQuestionText();
    }
    public String getCorrectAnswer() {
        return "______" + getQuestionText() + getCorrectAnswer();
    }


}
```

error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:124)
    at assignment9testpapers.FillInTheBlankQuestion.getQuestionText(FillInTheBlankQuestion.java:10)
```

Comment: Can you provide an error message? Don't forget we can't see line numbers in stack overflow.

Comment: I just added it to the bottom of the question; my bad

Comment: **Don't forget we can't see line numbers in Stack Overflow.** Wait, StringBuilder? This is not at all a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You left a lot out if I see line numbers that high.

Comment: Use comments to ask for more information or suggest improvements. **Avoid answering questions in comments.** @ScaryWombat

Comment: @ScaryWombat since I am calling it question.java should I even call it in the method?

Comment: @JohnnyDepp Maybe you mean to call the `super.getQuestionText ();`

Comment: @ScaryWombat I know what you're saying but then how would I modified the getQuestionText to have a blank in the toString?

Comment: `return "______________" + super.getQuestionText();`

Comment: that makes sense. thank you I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

In "public class FillInTheBlankQuestion" method "public String getQuestionText() you are calling the method inside itself, causing in infintite loop. If you are trying to use the method from superclass use super.getQuestionText().